Ubuntu 24.04 only ever uses 2 of the 4 built in speakers on my laptop
unfortunately I have a problem with my laptop on which I have installed Ubuntu 24.04 that it only ever uses 2 of the 4 speakers built into it.
The laptop is an HP Spectre x360 Convertible 13-w0XX, which is quite old and is no longer supported by Windows (11). However, as it is still completely adequate for my purposes, I wanted to try Ubuntu and am completely satisfied with the system.
The only thing that really bothers me, as the laptop is mainly used for media consumption, is that only 2 of the 4 speakers built into it can be used at the same time.
Under Windows, all 4 speakers were always used and the laptop sounded much better as a result.
The strange thing is that when I select ‘Analogue Sorround 4.0 Output’ in the sound settings, only the rear speakers work. If I select ‘Analogue Stereo Output’, only the front speakers work. So somehow Ubuntu seems to recognise the speakers, but it can't use them at the same time.
I've already done a bit of googling, but unfortunately couldn't find a suitable solution for me. I'm not very familiar with the command line, but I'm not afraid of it. I am therefore grateful for any help and thank you in advance
..::edit::..
This is the output of alsa-info.sh
http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=611c628dbb62d937fdd18f7038e815ac8b8f50db
